# Finding population median range from sample

Tags: estimation, median

Suppose we take a sample of size 5 from a continuous distribution. What is the probability that the population median lies between the smallest & largest number in our sample?

Comment: This is a common textbook question. Is this an exercise for some class?

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is the cdf, then the population median is $F^{-1}(1/2)$. If $X_{(i)}$ is the $i^{th}$ order statistic of a sample of size $n$, then the probability you're looking for is $P(X_{(1)} < F^{-1}(1/2) < X_{(n)})$. There are analytical formulas available for the joint distribution of order statistics.